# JasperReports list is changing frame height

Tags: jasper-reports

In my report title i have 2 frames one containing a list of max 3 rows(and min 0).
The issue is that when that list contains elements instead of using whats left of vertical space of that frame it grows and changes the title size. It looks like it wants to keep the margin or something else.
Does anyone have a clue of whats going on here? I'm pretty new using reporting tools :/

what i want is :
[image]

what i'm getting is
[image]

My report code:

```
<title>
    <band height="75" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="590" height="75" uuid="26162e44-080d-498d-ae25-9b7dd6cdaccc">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                <pen lineWidth="2.0"/>
            </box>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="589" height="30" uuid="6cda6f30-2571-4543-bd7b-a7ec9516ac74"/>
                <box topPadding="0"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Mapa de Exploração de Resultados até " + $P{MONTH} + " de " + $P{YEAR}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="589" height="18" uuid="9693c56a-35c3-4e2d-baf4-c8d49ca09185">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftIndent" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true"/>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="2"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{COMPANY_NAME} +"      NIF: " + $P{COMPANY_VAT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="590" y="0" width="209" height="75" uuid="e8c51c7b-8e0e-47a7-b240-3dffc34a53b4">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.layout.grid.weight.fixed" value="true"/>
                <property name="ShowOutOfBoundContent" value="true"/>
            </reportElement>
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="2.0"/>
            </box>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="57" y="0" width="69" height="18" uuid="07f54153-e59c-4dca-b8a8-8f5dd0307457"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Pressupostos]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="19" width="209" height="10" uuid="c9dc90e8-338c-445a-a392-ed5dd03a08d9">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.layout.grid.weight.fixed" value="true"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.allow.element.overlap" value="false"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="dataset_conditions" uuid="0e7bce2d-9da9-43fc-ab42-e22849e486e6">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{DATA_SOURCE_CONDITIONS}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="10" width="209">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="158" height="10" uuid="29fcd2ce-9677-4159-8270-47cb2697ff36">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightIndent" value="px"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font size="7"/>
                                <paragraph rightIndent="5"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="158" y="0" width="51" height="10" uuid="0dda909f-3e4c-42cb-b136-9134e92b86b9">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightIndent" value="px"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font size="6"/>
                                <paragraph rightIndent="5"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </frame>
    </band>
</title>
```

Comment: Try to use `stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"` for both frames (especially for left one)

Comment: @AlexK setting RelativeToTallestObject makes them with the same height nice :) however it's adds a lot of empty space causing the report to have 2 pages. can i remove the extra margin?  https://pasteboard.co/JbEBe81.png

Comment: The usage of `isStretchWithOverflow="true"` will help you

Comment: I'll look at that.